# WLCTL protocol detected by sniffer in an Android tablet

Tags: network, android, sniffer

I detected that my rooted Android tablet had a slow connection. Trying to find what is taking the bandwith, I installed a firewall (DroidWall) and I blocked all the applications thinking that one of them was doing it.

The weird thing was that my tablet still making connections to somewhere. So, I used an sniffer application (Wi.cap) to check it and yes, I found them. A few of them were ARP, ICMP and DNS connections. No problem with them. Nevertheless, **I found a LOT of connections about a "WLCTL" protocol** with 1 or 2KB of data. The source and the destination were MAC address. The destination is my tablet (I checked it), but I don't know what is that source that begins with "7A". Even, **the source and the destination have the SAME address, except for the FIRST byte**. (source begins with "7A" and destination, my tablet, begins with "78")

[image]

I tried to find more information, but I didn't find anything. I'm stuck, so this is my question:

**How can I find what process/application is doing these connections?**

I think that, knowing this, I can fix the problem...

Comment: Ya may want to check my other [answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/96635/82480) on detection of rouge Android processes, specifically the stuff related to `netstat` & `ls` commands for finding the pid and related executable... and what could go wrong if you've been popped with extra-bad malware.

Answer (score 1):

**WLCTL** (Web Listener Control) Utility is a UNIX utility, so I would recommend getting some sort of terminal emulator app and run the command "**top**" or "**htop**" to display the running processes, once you sort through the necessary normal processes and isolate the one that is sending out these packets, you can run the command "**pidof** [process name] " without the brackets and apostrophes and the output should be a number which uniquely identifies the process. From here its a simple command "**kill** [process id number]" again without the brackets or apostrophes.

Comment: This relies on the malware not having rootkit-like defenses.

Comment: Well, the problem was that: how to know what process is making what connections? The step "isolate the one that is sending these packages" says nothing about how to resolve this. Remember that there are a lot of process running, not only Android's process and the problematic. There are a lot of applications installed and uninstall one by one does not seem a efficient solution.