# Can this possibly infected SMS have been delivered with a cell-site simulator?

Tags: mobile

Very recently, I had received a message containing this text:

> #E(£ΘULÆ;iFΩ¥bi:iFΩké¤V7ud£*Φ 
>
>   M:ed9+FÅH9edYK6,ΘΔbr£1wÄ:mJi  
>
>   £ΦùÅΣMè£*$¤Z9 B#ΨMÑ0tJ_¥ΦL2   
>   Φ9#WLÆ7eh£Ç6IX2sf£9Ψ6         
>   DΩ¥B.Θ9mR9ØF.Θ2               
>   BΘ#WLÆΔvÜ1+W-ΘΔ

which is similar to what happened to [this post's](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139634/is-this-an-sms-hack-attempt/139716#139716) OP's staff member, except that in that case, they did not know what number was sending the texts and in my case, it appears to come from my service provider. Is it possible that the service provider's network was compromised and the message was delivered through that or is it more likely that an attacker with a cell-site simulator was the culprit?

The answer in the link provides very good suggestions in case of receiving messages like this, but even if I were to take the appropriate actions and the necessary safeguards, without weeding out the source, there's no reason I can't just get infected again (assuming that's what these texts are doing and I got infected the first time).

Comment: There's a third option: [SMS spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_spoofing). There's no guarantee it actually came from where it says it did.